How to get reel viewcount using official Instagram API (basic or graph) from the chatbot
I have a back-end chatbot that should have a feature of getting view_count for particular Instagram reels. There's an "unofficial" solution for the problem - that has a risk of my account to be banned.
https://medium.com/@yogeshsherawat/get-instagram-reels-view-count-7efc02b121b3
I don't want my account to be banned, so, I want to use official API but I haven't found a way of doing that with it. Also what's important, my chatbot is back-end only, not website, so I have no user to authenticate, and should use some kind of token for my requests, or provide a way to authorize my account with back-end only mode.
I plan to use Java, but solution on any language will help me (except of the Lisp and Haskell hehehe) - if you can recommend what exact API should I use and what settings should be made - thank you in advance!
I tried to investigate docs of basic API but it has mandatory authentication callback which is not applicable to my situation. Also I checked docs of Graph API and haven't found a feature for getting viewcount for reel.

"for particular Instagram reels" - "particular", how? Do you have an account that has access to those - or are we talking about just any reel, owned by any arbitrary user? If the latter, then you can of course forget about getting this kind of info via the official APIs.

"but it has mandatory authentication callback which is not applicable to my situation" - don't confuse getting an access token, with using an access token. You can of course implement the process to get an access token (in a not "backend-only" part of your application), and then use that token in your request made from the backend.

@CBroe thank you so much for checking on my question and providing the comments! Reels assumed to be open for everyone and accessible with any account that has access to instagram. Yeah I mean using access token - does it possible to just get it once and put into configuration, to not have ask for account authentication. I don't wanna turn off 2factor and hardcode login password in my chatbot. It's a telegram chatbot so it's not easy to make authentication proxy

"Reels assumed to be open for everyone and accessible with any account that has access to instagram." - on the frontend - yes. API access however is a completely different thing. If you're not the "owner" of the reel, then you won't be able to get any info about it via the official API.

@CBroe okay according to this - unofficial approach is only possible way to solve the task. Official APIs are incompatible with our goal and architecture. Okay, thank you so much for the help!
